# Output PHP Parser Script Variables to PHP form via Sessions

Tags: php, parsing, session, simplexml, session-variables

New to PHP, so bear with me...

I'm trying to send/make available the output variables from this simpleXml parser script to this other PHP file, which is supposed to send data to Brightcove's Media API.

**Sending Script:**

```
<?php
session_name("FeedParse");
session_start();
$_SESSION['bcName'] = $title;
$_SESSION['shortDescription'] = $description;
$_SESSION['remoteUrl'] = $videoFile;
$html = "";
$url = "http://feeds.nascar.com/feeds/video?command=search_videos&media_delivery=http&custom_fields=adtitle%2cfranchise&page_size=100&sort_by=PUBLISH_DATE:DESC&token=217e0d96-bd4a-4451-88ec-404debfaf425&any=franchise:%20Preview%20Show&any=franchise:%20Weekend%20Top%205&any=franchise:Up%20to%20Speed&any=franchise:Press%20Pass&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Practice%20Clips&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Highlights&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Final%20Laps&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Victory%20Lane&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Post%20Race%20Reactions&any=franchise:All%20Access&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Qualifying%20Clips&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Highlights&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Final%20Laps&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Victory%20Lane&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Post%20Race%20Reactions&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Qualifying%20Clips&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Highlights&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Final%20Laps&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Victory%20Lane&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Post%20Race%20Reactions&output=mrss";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true); // get namespaces

for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){ // will return the 50 most recent videos 
  $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->video;
  $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
  $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
  $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
  $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
  $titleid = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children($namespaces['bc'])->titleid;
  $m_attrs = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children($namespaces['media'])->content[0]->attributes();
  $videoFile = $m_attrs["url"];
  $html .= //"<h3>$title</h3>$description<p>$pubDate<p>$url<p>Video ID: $titleid<p>

print $title;
print $description;
print $videoFile;
// echo $html;/* tutorial for this script is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZLZkdiKGE0 */
}
//http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/media-write-api-php-example-upload-video
?>
```

Receiving Script:

```
  <?php 
session_start();
$title = $_SESSION['bcName'];
$description = $_SESSION['shortDescription'];
$videoFile = $_SESSION['remoteUrl'];

// Instantiate the Brightcove class
$bc = new Brightcove(
    '//readtoken//', //Read Token BC 
    '//writetoken//' //Write Token BC 
);

// Set the data for the new video DTO using the form values
$metaData = array(
  '$title' => $_POST['bcName'],
  '$description' => $_POST['bcShortDescription'],

);
//changed all the code below to what i think works for remoteUrl and URLs as opposed to actual video files
// Rename the file to its original file name (instead of temp names like "a445ertd3")
$url = $_URL['remoteUrl'];
//rename($url['tmp_name'], '/tmp/' . $url['name']);
//$url = '/tmp/' . $url['name'];

// Send the file to Brightcove
//Actually, this has been changed to send URL to BC, not file
echo $bc->createVideo($url,$metaData);

class Brightcove {
        public $token_read = 'UmILcDyAFKzjtWO90HNzc67X-wLZK_OUEZliwd9b3lZPWosBPgm1AQ..'; //Read Token from USA Today Sports BC
        public $token_write = 'svP0oJ8lx3zVkIrMROb6gEkMW6wlX_CK1MoJxTbIajxdn_ElL8MZVg..'; //Write Token from USA Today Sports BC 
        public $read_url = 'http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?';
        public $write_url = 'http://api.brightcove.com/services/post';

  public function __construct($token_read, $token_write = NULL ) {
    $this->token_read = $token_read;
    $this->token_write = $token_write;
  }

  public function createVideo($url = NULL, $meta) {
    $request = array();
    $post = array();
    $params = array();
    $video = array();

    foreach($meta as $key => $value) {
      $video[$key] = $value;
    }
    $params['token'] = $this->token_write;
    $params['video'] = $video;

    $post['method'] = 'create_video';
    $post['params'] = $params;

    $request['json'] = json_encode($post);

    if($file) {
      $request['file'] = '@' . $file;
    }

    // Utilize CURL library to handle HTTP request
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->write_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    // Responses are transfered in JSON, decode into PHP object
    $json = json_decode($response);

    // Check request error code and re-call createVideo if request
                // returned a 213 error. A 213 error occurs when you have 
                // exceeded your allowed number of concurrent write requests
    if(isset($json->error))  {
      if($json->error->code == 213) {
        return $this->createVideo($url, $meta);
      } else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    } else {
      return $response;
    }
  }
}

?>​
```

Did I set up sessions to work correctly here? Any ideas on why the receiving PHP script isn't picking up the data/variables outputted by the PHP feed parser script?

Comment: Where do `$title`, `$description`, and `$videoFile` come from in the sending script? And how is this data sent from the sending file to the receiving file? It looks to me like the sending file is just dumping the data out to the screen, not actually calling the receiving file in any way.

Comment: @Travesty3 I thought if the two PHP scripts/files were hosted on the same server, you could use sessions to allow $title, $description, $videoFile to be available to other PHP scripts/files. But you're saying I do need to use a POST method?

Comment: You set them in the session at the beginning of the script. Then you don't modify them, but instead modify the local variables that were used to set these session variables in the beginning. But this doesn't modify the session variables, just the local variables. This might work if you used `$_SESSION['bcName'] = &$title;` (note the `&` before the local variable name). This means that the variable is [assigned by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), and the session variable will change whenever the local variable changes, but I would avoid that confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In your sending script, it looks like you're setting the session variables at the beginning of the script and you're expecting them to get updated whenever the local variable changes. This won't happen with the way you've written it.

You could make this happen by [assigning the variables by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), by putting an ampersand (`&`) before the local variable name, but this can get kinda tricky in some scenarios, and it might be best to skip that headache and instead just update the session variable directly.

However, another issue is that you're attempting to store multiple values (50, as indicated by the code comments) into a scalar session variable. So every time your loop iterates, it would overwrite the previous value. Perhaps what would be better would be to use an array structure:

```
<?php
session_name("FeedParse");
session_start();
$_SESSION['videos'] = array(); // initialize a session variable 'videos' to be an array
$url = "http://feeds.nascar.com/feeds/video?command=search_videos&media_delivery=http&custom_fields=adtitle%2cfranchise&page_size=100&sort_by=PUBLISH_DATE:DESC&token=217e0d96-bd4a-4451-88ec-404debfaf425&any=franchise:%20Preview%20Show&any=franchise:%20Weekend%20Top%205&any=franchise:Up%20to%20Speed&any=franchise:Press%20Pass&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Practice%20Clips&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Highlights&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Final%20Laps&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Victory%20Lane&any=franchise:Sprint%20Cup%20Post%20Race%20Reactions&any=franchise:All%20Access&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Qualifying%20Clips&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Highlights&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Final%20Laps&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Victory%20Lane&any=franchise:Nationwide%20Series%20Post%20Race%20Reactions&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Qualifying%20Clips&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Highlights&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Final%20Laps&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Victory%20Lane&any=franchise:Truck%20Series%20Post%20Race%20Reactions&output=mrss";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true); // get namespaces

for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){ // will return the 50 most recent videos 
  $m_attrs = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children($namespaces['media'])->content[0]->attributes();

  // on each loop iteration, create a new array structure with the video info in it and
  // push it onto the 'video' array session variable
  $video = array(
    'bcName' => $xml->channel->item[$i]->video,
    'shortDescription' => $xml->channel->item[$i]->description,
    'remoteUrl' => $m_attrs["url"],
  );
  $_SESSION['videos'][] = $video;
}
```

Then, on your receiving script, you'll loop through `$_SESSION['videos']`:

```
<?php 
session_start();

// Instantiate the Brightcove class
$bc = new Brightcove(
    'UmILcDyAFKzjtWO90HNzc67X-wLZK_OUEZliwd9b3lZPWosBPgm1AQ..', //Read Token from USA Today Sports BC 
    'svP0oJ8lx3zVkIrMROb6gEkMW6wlX_CK1MoJxTbIajxdn_ElL8MZVg..' //Write Token from USA Today Sports BC 

foreach ((array)$_SESSION['videos'] as $video) {
    $title = $video['bcName'];
    $description = $video['shortDescription'];
    $videoFile = $video['remoteUrl'];
    // The code below this line may need to be adjusted. It does not seem quite right.
    // Are you actually sending anything to this script via POST? Or should those just
    // be the values we set above?
    // What is $_URL? Should that just be the $videoFile value?


    // Set the data for the new video DTO using the form values
    $metaData = array(
      '$title' => $_POST['bcName'],
      '$description' => $_POST['bcShortDescription'],

    );
    //changed all the code below to what i think works for remoteUrl and URLs as opposed to actual video files
    // Rename the file to its original file name (instead of temp names like "a445ertd3")
    $url = $_URL['remoteUrl'];
    //rename($url['tmp_name'], '/tmp/' . $url['name']);
    //$url = '/tmp/' . $url['name'];

    // Send the file to Brightcove
    //Actually, this has been changed to send URL to BC, not file
    echo $bc->createVideo($url,$metaData);
}
```

### IMPORTANT NOTE:

Keep in mind that this will call the API once for each video in the session (sounds like up to 50 each time). So you'll be making 50 cURL requests on each run of this script. That seems a bit heavy, but perhaps that's expected. It would be worth investigating if their API allows you to compile the data into one call and send it all up at once, as opposed to connecting, sending the data, parsing the response, and disconnecting, 50 times.

Comment: Wow! I can't thank you enough for all your feedback here, really appreciate it! I will dive into your suggestion momentarily, but one think you said caught my attention: The Brightcove API does allow you to pass an entire JSON request full of data, it looks like towards the end of the receiving script (the 2nd script I posted) it's passing JSON, do you think there's a way to directly submit a JSON feed from my parser script directly to this part of the code in the 2nd script that passes JSON directly to the Brightcove API?

Comment: I tried to run the parser script with the changes you suggested and it's giving me a: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [no active file] on line 0

Comment: It looks like there's a way to send data to the Brightcove API using their "buildJSONRequest" function takes data from form inputs and creates the JSON-RPC object that is passed in the create_video method. [API documentation](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/javascript-media-api-examples)